# Angular HttpClient Get Service Returning Too Early

Tags: angular, ionic3, rxjs, angular-httpclient

I'm trying to convert my old Ionic Angular Http code to the new Httpclient format, but the Get service is returning control to the calling function too early, so it doesn't get the returned data.

I've tried using async/await, but it makes no difference to the control flow.

I'm new to observables, so I'm sure it's something I'm not doing correctly, but I can't figure out what.

These are the functions from my code, with the new format of the getAsJson function, using the subscribe functionality of Httpclient. I only want to return the data from the http call, so I haven't included "observe: 'response'" in the options parameter.

loadLoyaltyDetails calls getLoyaltyDetails, which does a few other things than shown here and then calls getAsJson.

Functions:

```ts
loadLoyaltyDetails(): Promise<void> {
  return this.loyalty.getLoyaltyDetails().then(data => {
    console.log("in loadLoyaltyDetails, data =", data);
  })
  .catch(this.handleServiceLoadingError.bind(this))
}

getLoyaltyDetails(): Promise<LoyaltyDetails> {
  return this.callApi.getAsJson("/loyalty/url");
}

getAsJson(path: string): Promise<any> {
  let opts = this.getRequestOptions();
  console.log("in getAsJson, path = ", path);

  return this.http.get<HttpResponse<HttpEventType.Response>>(`${environment.API_URL}${path}`, opts)
    .subscribe(
      (res) => {
        console.log("in getAsJson, res = ", res);
        return res;
      },
      (err) => {
        console.log("in getAsJson, err = ", err);
        this.checkResponseForUnauthorized(err);
      }
    )
}
```

Console Log Messages

```
in getAsJson, path = /loyalty/url

in loadLoyaltyDetails, data = 
Object { closed: false, _parent: null, _parents: null, _subscriptions: (1) […], syncErrorValue: null, syncErrorThrown: false, syncErrorThrowable: false, isStopped: false, destination: {…} }

Using current token

in getAsJson, path = /other/url

in getAsJson, res = {…}
    endDate: "2019-01-08"
    numberOfShiftsRequired: 18
    numberOfShiftsWorked: 0
    startDate: "2019-01-08"

in getAsJson, res = Array []
```

As the log messages show, loadLoyaltyDetails calls getAsJson first, but gets a bunch of gobbledegook back straight away. Then getAsJson is called by another function, receives back the data for the first call, then the second call.

I was expecting the 'in loadLoyaltyDetails, data = ' line to appear after the first set of data is returned.

This is what I can't figure out i.e. how can I ensure control is not returned to loadLoyaltyDetails before the data has been returned?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `subscribe` function returns a [Subscribtion](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Subscription.js~Subscription.html) object immediately and won't pause the execution of your code until the subscribed observable actually emits a value. `Subscribtion` objects aren't used to get the data from the Observable but only to unsubscribe from the Observable you previously subscribed to (Note that you don't have to unsubscribe from Observables returned by the `HttpClient` as they complete and therefore unsubscribe automatically).

By calling `return this.http.get(..).subscribe(..)` you return this (to you useless) Subscribtion object all the way to your `loadLoyaltyDetails()` function, where you log it as the `data` object.

Instead you should return Observables up until the point where you actually need the data from the Observable (i suppose this is `loadLoyaltyDetails()` for you). This is where you subscribe and in the `subscribe` function you do the things you need to do with the objects emitted by you're Observable (in your case the http response body). 
Typically you would set some component variable that is displayed in your html template to a value emitted by an Observable. You could even defer the subscribtion to your template with the [AsyncPipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe) and don't subscribe manually at all.

If you don't need to handle the full HttpResponse but only want to get the JSON body and handle errors you could do something like:

```ts
localLoyaltyDetails: LoyaltyDetails;

// Note that this function returns nothing especially no Subscribtion object
loadLoyaltyDetails(): void {
  // supposing this is where you need your LoyaltyDetails you subscribe here
  this.loyalty.getLoyaltyDetails().subscribe(loyaltyDetails => {
    // handle your loyaltyDetails here
    console.log("in loadLoyaltyDetails, data =", loyaltyDetails);
    this.localLoyaltyDetails = loyaltyDetails;
  });
}

getLoyaltyDetails(): Observable<LoyaltyDetails> {
  // We call getAsJson and specify the type we want to return, in this case 
  // LoyaltyDetails. The http response body we get from the server at the given url, 
  // in this case "/loyalty/url", has to match the specified type (LoyaltyDetails).
  return this.callApi.getAsJson<LoyaltyDetails>("/loyalty/url");
}

// Don't subscribe in this function and instead return Observables up until the 
// point where you actually need the data from the Observable.
// T is the type variable of the JSON object that the http get request should return.
getAsJson<T>(path: string): Observable<T> {
  let opts = this.getRequestOptions(); 
  console.log("in getAsJson, path = ", path);

  return this.http.get<T>(`${environment.API_URL}${path}`, opts)
    .pipe(
      // you could peek into the data stream here for logging purposes 
      // but don't confuse this with subscribing
      tap(response => console.log("in getAsJson, res = ", response)),
      // handle http errors here as this is your service that uses the HttpClient
      catchError(this.handleError) 
    );
}

// copied from the Angular documentation
private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
  if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
    // A client-side or network error occurred. Handle it accordingly.
    console.error('An error occurred:', error.error.message);
  } else {
    // The backend returned an unsuccessful response code.
    // The response body may contain clues as to what went wrong,
    console.error(
      `Backend returned code ${error.status}, ` +
      `body was: ${error.error}`);
  }
  // return an observable with a user-facing error message
  return throwError(
    'Something bad happened; please try again later.');
};
```

You can read more about the `HttpClient` and the `handleError` function in the [Angular HttpClient Docs](https://angular.io/guide/http). You could also write a `handleError` function that returns a default value on errors like the one in the [Angular Tutorial (Http Error Handling)](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6#error-handling).

---

**Edit regarding your comment:**

Generate an Observable from your Promise with the `defer` function (the generation of the Observable, and thus the execution of the Promise, is deferred until a subscriber actually subscribes to the Observable).

```ts
import { defer } from 'rxjs';

// defer takes a Promise factory function and only calls it when a subscriber subscribes 
// to the Observable. We then use mergeMap to map the authToken we get from  
// getLoggedInToken to the Observable we get from getAsJson.
getLoyaltyDetails(): Observable<LoyaltyDetails> {
  return defer(this.login.getLoggedInToken)
    .pipe(
      mergeMap(authToken =>
        this.callApi.getAsJson<LoyaltyDetails>(authToken, "/loyalty/details/NMC")
      )
    );
}
```

---

Note that loadLoyaltyDetails returns nothing i.e. `void`.

```ts
private details: LoyaltyDetails;

loadLoyaltyDetails(): void {
  // supposing this is where you need your LoyaltyDetails you subscribe here
  this.loyalty.getLoyaltyDetails().subscribe(loyaltyDetails => {
    console.log("in loadLoyaltyDetails, data =", loyaltyDetails);

    // set a local variable to the received LoyaltyDetails
    this.details = loyaltyDetails;
  });
}
```

---

As your loadLoyaltyDetails returns nothing you just call the function at the time you need it to be executed.

```ts
this.loader.wraps<void>(
  this.loadShifts().then(() => this.loadLoyaltyDetails())
);
```

Comment: Thx @fridoo. I think I understand the interaction between the levels a bit better now. However, I'm not sure what the <T>s are for. When I try putting them into my IDE as above, it says 'Can't find name T' and when I try to use HttpResponse, it keeps complaining that the Type Observable<{} | HttpResponse<HttpEventType.Response>> is not assignable to type <HttpResponse<HttpEventType.Response>>. I need getAsJson to be a general http function rather than one that is tied to a particular type. How can I make it do this?

Comment: @AlphaBeta The T is a type variable which is a placeholder for a specific given type (see: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html). I used generics so that getAsJson isn't tied to a particular type and can be called to return any specific given type. Whenever you call getAsJson you now have to specify the type you want the function to return, e.g. when you call getAsJson<LoyaltyDetails>("myUrl") you tell the getAsJson function to return an Observable<LoyaltyDetails> object. You probably get erros because you're calling getAsJson somewhere without specifying the return type.

Comment: thx for clarifying, I thought it might be something like that. However, after struggling all morning, I'm still getting an error with getLoyaltyDetails. The code I'm using is: getLoyaltyDetails(): Observable<LoyaltyDetails> {
    return this.login.getLoggedInToken().then(async (authToken) => {
      return this.callApi.getAsJson<LoyaltyDetails>(authToken, "/loyalty/details/NMC")
    });
  } (you may have to copy that code into a text editor so it's easier to read)

Comment: ...and the error I'm getting is: Type 'Promise<Observable<LoyaltyDetails>>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<LoyaltyDetails>'. I can't figure out where it's getting the Promise from and to stop it doing that. Any ideas?

Comment: That's got rid of that error message, but I have another one now at the loadLoyaltyDetails level. The message is now saying: Type 'Subscription' is not assignable to type 'Promise<void>'. So, one question is: Why is it thinking a Subscription is being returned, when getLoyaltyDetails is specifying a type of LoyaltyDetails? The other is: How can I end up with a Promise in loadLoyaltyDetails?

Comment: One thought I've had is, would it be easier to move the subscribe functioinality to the provider level and return the required data in the required format from there or does it have to be at the component level?

Comment: You probably have a return statement in `loadLoyaltyDetails` and specified a return type. Check if the function looks the one in my answer! `loadLoyaltyDetails` shouldn't return anything from how I understand your code. You usually subscribe late than early, so having the subscription at the component level in normal. But it doesn't necessarily have to be like this and I'm no Angular expert.

Comment: Yes, there is a return statement. loadLoyaltyDetails in full just sets some class properties to the returned data, then returns to the calling function, which does this: const loadLoyaltyDetailsPromise = this.loadLoyaltyDetails();
    this.loader.wraps<void>(
      this.loadShifts().then(() => loadLoyaltyDetailsPromise)
    ); 
i.e. it is called after the main data for the page has been retrieved. Would this need to be adjusted too, to fit in with the way Httpclient works or can it be left the same? Also, would loadLoyaltyDetails need to return a Promise or can it just return a void?

Comment: @AlphaBeta please edit your question and add the missing code so I can get a full picture of how your functions interact with each other.

Comment: Well, I tried to get the observable way to work, but ran into so many stoppers that I ended up using .toPromise() on the calls and going back to the original code for processing the return. I just kept getting the subscription object being returned from the getAsJson function first and then a second return from the http.get returned nothing and this was the only way I could consistently get the correct data returned at the correct time. Oh well, I guess I'll have to have another go at observables at a later date. Thx for all your help though @fridoo, it's been very informative.

Comment: Ok. Have you had a look at my latest edit to my answer though? The key should be to generally never use `return getHttpRequestObservable().subscribe(..)` as this returns the `Subscription` object you're having problems with. Instead you should just call `getHttpRequestObservable.subscribe(jsonBody => doSomethingWith(jsonBody))` without any return statement. You code execution will continue but the `subscribe` will quietly wait in the background for the observable to emit something. This code could be wrapped in a function, e.g. `onButtonClick()` which gets called when the data is requested.